# Prove cyclic group with one generator can have atmost 2 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

Prove cyclic group with one generator can have atmost 2 elements .

Attempt

Consider a cyclic group generated by $a \neq e$  ie G =  .So G is also generated by <$a^{-1}$> .Now Since it is given that there is one generator thus 
$a = a^{-1}$ which implies that $a^{2}=1$ .Using $a^{O(G)}=e$ .$O(G)=2 $

But i am not confident with this

Thanks

Comment: In general $a^n=e$ and $a^m=e$ does not imply $n=m$, so you can't conclude $|G|=2$ if that's the logic you're using. Instead given $a^2=e$ just check $\langle a\rangle=\{e,a\}$ directly.

Comment: To tighten up the end of the proof, use that $a^n = e \Rightarrow O(G) | n$.

Comment: then $O(G) $ divides $2$ (not equal) which implies $O(G)\leq 2$ which means that the group have at least two elements

Comment: @K.Dutta you didn't mention in the beginning that $G$ is finite, so what do you mean by $a^{O(G)} = e$? Instead, you want to use the fact that if $a$ has finite order and $k$ is an integer, then $a^k = e$ if and only if $O(a)\, | \,k$. In your case, since $a^2 = e$,  $O(a)\, | \, 2$, which implies $a = e$ or $O(a) = 2$.

Comment: @kobe Why can it be more than 2

Comment: @kobe  i am little bit confused .can you elaborate your answer a bit

Comment: You've already determined that $a^2 = e$. Using the fact I mentioned earlier, this implies that the order of $a$ divides $2$. So the order of $a$ is at most $2$, which implies the order of $G$ is at most $2$.

Comment: @kobe if o(a) divides 2 ,then how is order of a atmost 2

Comment: Think of it this way (which is more to point of what I wrote in the answer below) -- the positive divisors of $2$ are $1$ and $2$. Each divisor is of course no greater than $2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary element $g \in G$. Since $G=\langle a \rangle$, then there is $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $g=a^k=a^{2q+r}$, where $r \in \{0,1\}$ is the remainder of the euclidean division of $k$ by $2$, and $q$ is the quotient. Then $g=(a^2)^q \cdot a^r = 1^q \cdot a^r = a^r$ for some $r \in\{0,1\}$. So $g \in \{1, a\}$ which has at most two elements.

Comment: What is relation between k and 2q

Comment: Consider the euclidean division of $k$ by $2$. Call $q$ the quotient, and $r$ the remainder. Then $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$, $k = 2q+r$ and $0 \leq r < 2$.

Comment: how is a^{2} = 1

Comment: By your argument: $a$ and $a^{-1}$ both generate $G$ which has exactly one generator.

Comment: lovely answer , h

Comment: @posilon : I think that’s not quite complete. The question only refers to “a cyclic group with one generator”, so it cannot yet be deduced that for any g in G, g^2 = e. I think we can use Eulers Phi function. Let the order of G be N. Since it has only one generator, then “1” is the only number that is co-prime to N. N can only be 2. By showing that N is exactly 2, we have also showed N is at most 2.

Comment: @NetUser5y62 We didn't initially show that $g^2 = e$ for any $g \in G$. We (actually the OP) showed that $a^2 = e$ for any *generator* $a$ of $G$.

Answer (score 5):

Since $a^2 = e$, either $a$ is the identity or $a$ has order $2$. If $a$ is the identity, $G  = \{e\}$; if $a$ has order $2$, $G = \{e,a\}$.

Comment: ok thanks i  get it

Comment: sorry i didn't accept your answer which  doesn't mean it didn't helped me .

Comment: No need to be sorry. Glad to be of help. :)

Comment: I think it does not immediately follow that a^2 = e, since that was the part to be proved in the question.

Comment: @NetUser5y62 that $a^2 = e$ was already shown in the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The question only refers to “a cyclic group with one generator”, so it cannot immediately be deduced that for any $g$ in $G$, $g^2 = e$ I think we can use Eulers Phi function. Let the order of $G$ be $N$. Since it has only one generator, then “$1$” is the only number that is co-prime to $N$. $N$ can only be $2$. By showing that $N$ is exactly $2$, we have also showed $N$ is at most $2$.

Comment: That $g^2 = e$ was shown by the OP as part of the question.